# "Release", "free", or "delete allocated memory"?

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, terminology, programming

> 1. release the allocated memory.
> 2. free the allocated memory.
> 3. delete the allocated memory.

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the differences have more to do with the computer language behind them. **Delete** is inappropriate. Assuming C++ or similar, an *object* is being deleted, and its associated memory is automatically freed thereafter. **Free** will be understood by any C-family programmer. **Release** probably will be too but when you are writing for a C audience, stick with C terminology. (Release is more often used with respect to a connection pool, an OS resource, but not memory—in C. In another language, your mileage may vary.)

Comment: This also raises the question why the words _free_ and _release_ were chosen for deallocating memory, while the opposite, allocating memory, is never called _catch_ or _capture_. Oh well.

Comment: I always thought _malloc_ sounded like a make of candy.

Comment: **Release** is a keyword in Objective-C (which uses reference counting), and decreases the reference count of an object: it will be _deallocated_ (ie deleted) once all references have been released.

Comment: @Mr Lister: So many of my students *torture* the memory that the words *free* or *release* are appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Generally memory allocation in programming languages operates in pairs of functions, and as Andrew Lazarus states, this depends on the language in question. Manual memory management is most common in C-style languages, while many others (including Java) have automatic management through garbage collection etc, so the programmer has not to worry about allocating or deallocating memory.

In **C** the functions are `malloc()`/`free()` (there are different variants for allocation, eg `calloc()`). So here you would definitely use the second statement, *to free allocated memory*.

**Objective-C** uses mostly reference counting (which in the current version is done automatically), and here you create objects using `[[MyClass alloc] init]`, or short `[MyClass new]` (though this is not conventionally used). Note that this is about *objects*, not 'raw' memory. For memory you'd use the C functions. When you want to keep a handle to an object alive you call `[myObject retain]` which adds one to the object's reference count, and to get rid of it you call `[myObject release]`. Once there are no references to an object it is *deallocated*, and it's memory freed. So here you would almost use the first statement, but for an object which is *released*.

In **C++** you create objects with `new` and delete them with `delete` (last time I did this—I have not used C++ for a long time). Again you *delete an object*, not memory.

In a language-agnostic context I would say the first two (release/free) are mostly synonymous, while I would not use the third one at all.